# Vuejs Unknown custom element (Imported component error)

Tags: vue.js, components

I basically import 2-3 components in a parent component and based on the button clicks I simply hide and show some components. In every component I have Back and Next buttons, when they clicked, I show different components in different situations. Here's a simple example of one my components;

```
<template>
  <div>
      <transition name="fade" appear> 
        <div class="justify-center">
          <form @submit.prevent="submitFormTest" v-if="!back && !configuration">
             Bunch of code here is irrelevant with my question...
           <!-- Buttons -->
          <div class="text-center mt-4">
              <button @click="back = true" class="btn-w-orange mr-2" type="button">Back</button>
              <button @click="nextButton" class="btn-w-orange" type="button">Next</button>
          </div>
          </form>

          <modalOpMode v-if="back"></modalOpMode>
          <modalConnection v-if="configuration && !back"></modalConnection >
        </div>
      </transition>
  </div>
</template>
```

and here is my script;

```
<script>
import modalConnection from "./modalConnection";
import modalOpMode from "./modalOpMode "

export default {
  data(){
    return {
      configuration: false,
      back: false
    }
  },
  components: {
    modalOpMode,
    modalConnection,
  },
  methods: {
    nextButton(){
      this.configuration = true;
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

I statically imported two other components to display when back and next button is clicked. Everything is okay when I go for Next button for ALL MY COMPONENTS. (There are other components that I get the same error.). But the problem occurs when I click the back button. When Next is clicked, the form is hidden and `modalConnection` is visible as it should but when Back is clicked, I only see a blank page because the `modalOpMode` gives me the following error;

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <modalOpMode> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

I'm pretty sure that I import the component in the correct way, the path, the component name, the usage, everything is normal because I do that with the other one `modalConnection` and that one works all good. If you want to check my modalOpMode component, here it is;

```
<template>
    <transition name="fade" appear> 
      <div>
        <form @submit.prevent="submitFormTest" v-if="configuration == ''">
         There are four radio buttons that bound with v-model to change the value of configuration variable
        </form>
        <!-- Modal Comp1-->
        <modalComp1 v-if="configuration == 'comp1'"></modalComp1>
        <!-- Modal Comp2 -->
        <modalComp2 v-if="configuration == 'comp2'"></modalComp2>
        <!-- Modal Comp3-->
        <modalComp3 v-if="configuration == 'comp3'"></modalComp3>
        <!-- Modal Comp4 -->
        <modalComp4 v-if="configuration == 'comp4'"></modalComp4 >
      </div>
    </transition>
</template>
```

In here I imported 4 other components and bound them to a variable called `configuration`. When the variable is equal to something like comp1 or comp2 as above, I simply display the relevant component and hide the other content.

As I said before, when I click the next button and show the components, it's all good, but I can't go back, it gives me the above error. What am I doing wrong or what am I missing here? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In Components you have modalOperatingMode instead of modalOpMode

Comment: Actually this is my bad, I forgot to change it when asking the question here, so it's not the reason why it doesn't work. I'll edit the question now. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: Okay, can you add a screenshot of your (relevant) folder structure?